# How to fix jquery datatable cell width?

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

How to fix data table with content size?

```
th, td { white-space: nowrap; }
div.dataTables_wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I tried to use w**hite-space: nowrap;** but not working.
Please check my attached screen shot.

[image]

Comment: @CasBloem - Overflow hidden won't fix that, it'll just hide the overflowing content. OP - have you tried width: auto? They all look like the same width to me, which would imply their width is being set in a way you wouldn't want it to (being divided by % or explicitly set to ~90px?).

Comment: You can try `word-wrap: break-word;`

Answer (score -1):

Let's try to solve your problem;

Do you have the **DataTables'** `autoWidth` disabled? Try to enable it.
(default enabled so removing the false will also work)

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "autoWidth": true
} );
```